# Keep timer and location running in background Swift

Tags: swift, timer, cllocation

I am trying to keep the timer and location updated whilst the app is in the background/ the phone is locked.

I have tried a number of online solutions and as of yet nothing has worked.

My code is below:

```
class NewRunViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let regionInMeters : Double = 200
    private var seconds = 0
    private var timer: Timer?
    private var distance = Measurement(value: 0, unit: UnitLength.meters)
    private var locationList: [CLLocation] = []
    var polyLine: MKPolyline = MKPolyline()

    @IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var DistanceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var PaceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var StartButtonLabel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ResetButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var StopPauseButtonLabel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView4: GADBannerView!

    @IBAction func StartButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        ResetButtonOutlet.isHidden = true
        StopPauseButtonLabel.isHidden = false
        StartButtonLabel.isHidden = true
        updateDisplay()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
          self.eachSecond()
        }
        startLocationUpdates()

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
            MapView.showsUserLocation = true
        }

        else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            MapView.showsUserLocation = true
        }

        else {
           let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Just to let you know...", message:
               "Your location services are not enabled, you can still use the timer but the distance and pace won't show without your location. You can enable location services in your device settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)
           alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))

           self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }


    @IBAction func StopButtonLabel(_ sender: UIButton) {

        StopPauseButtonLabel.isHidden = true
        ResetButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        StartButtonLabel.isHidden = false
        timer?.invalidate()
    }


    @IBAction func ResetButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        StartButtonLabel.isHidden = false
        seconds = 0
        distance = Measurement(value: 0, unit: UnitLength.meters)
        locationList.removeAll()
        timer?.invalidate()
        updateDisplay()
        MapView.removeOverlays(MapView.overlays)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkLocationServices()
        timer?.invalidate()
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        StopPauseButtonLabel.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

        bannerView4.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-6331942799423798/9472120281"
        bannerView4.rootViewController = self
        bannerView4.load(GADRequest())
        MapView.delegate = self
    }

    func setUpLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }

    func centreViewOnUserLocation() {
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
            MapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func checkLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            setUpLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorisation()
        }

        else {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Just so you know...", message:
            "Sadly, your location services aren't enabled, change them in your settings to track your pace and distance.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func checkLocationAuthorisation() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case.authorizedWhenInUse:
            MapView.showsUserLocation = true
            centreViewOnUserLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break

        case.denied:
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Just to let you know...", message:
                "Your location services are not enabled, you can still run but without your distance and pace. If you change your mind later you can enable location services in your device settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            break

        case.notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break

        case.restricted:
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Just to let you know...", message:
                "Your location services are restricted, check your device settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            break

        case.authorizedAlways:
            MapView.showsUserLocation = true
            centreViewOnUserLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        @unknown default:
            break
        }
      }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        let centre = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: centre, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        MapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

          for newLocation in locations {
            let howRecent = newLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow
            guard newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 20 && abs(howRecent) < 10 else { continue }

            if let lastLocation = locationList.last {
              let delta = newLocation.distance(from: lastLocation)
              distance = distance + Measurement(value: delta, unit: UnitLength.meters)

              let coordinates = [lastLocation.coordinate, newLocation.coordinate]
              MapView.addOverlay(MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: 2))
              let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: newLocation.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 200, longitudinalMeters: 200)
              MapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            }

              locationList.append(newLocation)
          }
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkLocationAuthorisation()
    }

    func eachSecond() {
      seconds += 1
      centreViewOnUserLocation()
      updateDisplay()
    }

    private func updateDisplay() {
      let formattedDistance = FormatDisplay.distance(distance)
      let formattedTime = FormatDisplay.time(seconds)
      let formattedPace = FormatDisplay.pace(distance: distance,
                                             seconds: seconds,
                                             outputUnit: UnitSpeed.minutesPerMile)

        DistanceLabel.text = "Distance:  \(formattedDistance)"
        TimeLabel.text = "Time:  \(formattedTime)"
        PaceLabel.text = "Pace:  \(formattedPace)"
    }

    private func startLocationUpdates() {
      locationManager.delegate = self
      locationManager.activityType = .fitness
      locationManager.distanceFilter = 10
      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        centreViewOnUserLocation()
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
      guard let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline else {
        return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
      }
      let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
      renderer.strokeColor = .blue
      renderer.lineWidth = 3
      return renderer
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally, neither a timer nor anything else will run when the app is not frontmost; the app freezes. It is possible to rig a location manager to run in the background, but I don’t see you doing that anywhere in the code you have shown; and of course you also need the special background mode capability. The timer, I believe, will still not magically run in the background, though there should be no need for it to do so as you can always check the time when the app is foregrounded.